# cloudflare: CORS after Image Resizing

Tags: cors, cloudflare, image-resizing

My domain (for example example.com) uses cloudflare and when I try to use link from it on another domain without resizing (for example https://example.com/1.png) then everything works, if with resizing (for example https://example.com/cdn-cgi/image/width=1024, quality=75/1. png) then I get an error like Access to XMLHttpRequest at ‘https://example.com/cdn-cgi/image/width=1024,quality=75/1.png’ from origin ‘second.com’ has been blocked by CORS policy: No ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ header is present on the requested resource. ‘’

I don’t see cors settings in Cloudflare panel and didn’t find answer on this community.

Please help me, best regards

Answer (score -1):

You should use workers to add these security headers